# Find the equation of parabola passing through $(-1, 6), (1, 4), (2, 9)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A(the?) equation of parabola is $y = ax^2 + bx + c$. That gives the equations below:

\begin{align*}
6 & = a - b + c\\
4 & = a + b + c\\
9 & = 4a + 2b + c
\end{align*}

Then I simply solve for $(a, b, c)$ and substitute it into $y = ax^2 + bx + c$, correct? I guess it can be considered a quick question :)

Comment: Yes, this is correct.

Comment: @ Nikhil, It didn't generate a whole buncha discussion, but hopefully it will help someone out in the future. Thank you :)

Comment: Your approach is correct.  Are you able to solve these?  Adding the first two is a good start.

Comment: Subtract the first two even better ;) to find -2b = 2 instead of 2a+ 2c = 10

Answer (score 0):

The graphical solution gives (Spoiler):

> $(a,b,c) = (2,-1,3)$

[image: graphical solution coefficent system]  $\quad\quad\quad$
[image: result]